# Web API self host with home page

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I have a Windows service which needs a web admin portal for managing and controlling configurations and should be exposed by the same Windows service (I don't want to use IIS).

I tried Web API self host but I am not able to set a start up page for my port. I tried the below code, please help me to set up home page for my self hosed web API.

```
    const string BaseAddress = "http://localhost:8080";

    static void HostAPI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting service");
        HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(BaseAddress);
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             "Default",
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}" }
        );

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine($"Service started at {BaseAddress}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an error ?

Comment: There was no error in my solution, a confusion was normal web api project if there is an index.html file added to the project it takes as the home page, but not for self hosed applications. Sorry i haven't included this in my question.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an action for your homepage and return html from it.

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        // add your homepage html here
        response.Content = new StringContent("<html><body>Your Home Page</body></html>");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
       return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kahbazi for your answer, yes I can now read my html file and put in the response.Content in your solution.